# SyntaxError: Missing ) after argument list in Mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am new to `node.js`. I have connected the MySQL database successfully. I am able to do simple select query, but when I try a query with multiple JOIN it throws me an error saying **Missing ) after argument list**

```
app.get('/quotes', function (req, res) {
mc.query(`SELECT p.sku,pa.attribute_value as is_seen, pa1.attribute_value as rating,m.projects_unit_id as project_id,m.version,sp.total_sale_price as total_price,
    p.published_on,im.image_url as image, im1.image_url as  pdf_link FROM my_designs m INNER JOIN product p on m.sku=p.sku and p.is_deleted=0 and p.is_published=1 
    INNER JOIN supplier_product sp on sp.product_id=p.product_id and sp.is_deleted=0 
    LEFT JOIN images im on im.`key`=m.sku and im.image_type=36 and im.is_deleted=0 
    LEFT JOIN images im1 on im1.`key` = m.sku and im1.image_type = 15 and im1.is_deleted=0 
    LEFT JOIN product_attributes pa on pa.common_id = p.sku and pa.is_deleted = 0 and pa.attribute_name = 'is_seen' 
    LEFT JOIN product_attributes pa1 on pa1.common_id = p.sku and pa1.is_deleted = 0 and pa1.attribute_name = 'rating' 
    WHERE m.user_id=? and m.is_deleted=0 and m.projects_unit_id is not null ORDER BY p.published_on DESC`, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    return res.send({ error: false, data: JSON.stringify(results), message: 'quote list.' });
}); });
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using **Template Literals**

- Template literals are enclosed by the ``` back-tick (``) ```  (grave accent)
  character instead of double or single quotes.
- **Template literals can contain placeholders**. These are indicated by
  the dollar sign and curly braces `(${expression})`.

[**Here is the documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

So, instead of **im.`key`** you have to use **`im.${key}`**

So, your code becomes,

```
app.get('/quotes', function (req, res) {

mc.query(`SELECT p.sku,pa.attribute_value as is_seen, pa1.attribute_value as rating,m.projects_unit_id as project_id,m.version,sp.total_sale_price as total_price,
    p.published_on,im.image_url as image, im1.image_url as  pdf_link FROM my_designs m INNER JOIN product p on m.sku=p.sku and p.is_deleted=0 and p.is_published=1 
    INNER JOIN supplier_product sp on sp.product_id=p.product_id and sp.is_deleted=0 
    LEFT JOIN images im on im.${key}=m.sku and im.image_type=36 and im.is_deleted=0 
    LEFT JOIN images im1 on im1.${key} = m.sku and im1.image_type = 15 and im1.is_deleted=0 
    LEFT JOIN product_attributes pa on pa.common_id = p.sku and pa.is_deleted = 0 and pa.attribute_name = 'is_seen' 
    LEFT JOIN product_attributes pa1 on pa1.common_id = p.sku and pa1.is_deleted = 0 and pa1.attribute_name = 'rating' 
    WHERE m.user_id=? and m.is_deleted=0 and m.projects_unit_id is not null ORDER BY p.published_on DESC`, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    return res.send({ error: false, data: JSON.stringify(results), message: 'Todos list.' });
    }
);

});
```

**Ps:**

As you got the reason for some others to know, **key** is a `reserved` word.

Comment: actually **key** is a reserved word. so that was throwing the error.

Comment: okay it might have said you something about that key in your error

Comment: also `${key}` is the standard syntax to use, because if you are using any lint, `key` will throw an error, so you should use `${key}`

Comment: @r93, you can accept and  vote my answer, if you find it useful.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You need to use `$` around your variables, this is how you need to compose your query,

```
`Select * from Table where key = ${key} and otherkey = ${otherkey}`
```

Comment: thank you for the help. So in the query i was using tilde character which was causing that error. So i had changed that to single quotes which worked.